# Libraries for programmatically editing an image?

Tags: javascript, .net, image, edit

I am looking for a library in .net or javascript that will allow me to programmatically edit an image. For example, I would like to crop an image to an arbitrary 2D polygon (e.g. star- or wedge-shaped) from within a program.

EDIT: The preferred languages would be C# or javascript

Comment: I think .NET can do it with the framework, no additional library required.

Comment: For "cropping" to something other than a rectangle, I think what you really want to do is AND the original image with some arbitrary monochrome mask image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

Comment: Yes, this seems to do all I need: c# api and arbitrary cropping by using masks...thank you :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Otherwise, the answer is at risk of losing its usefulness due to link rot.

Comment: ImageMagick has existed for at least 15 years - bit rot???

Answer (score 1):

**HTML5's canvas element** allows for cropping. Here's [one explanation](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/) of a simple cropping.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function(){
        // draw cropped image
        var sourceX = 150;
        var sourceY = 0;
        var sourceWidth = 150;
        var sourceHeight = 150;
        var destWidth = sourceWidth;
        var destHeight = sourceHeight;
        var destX = canvas.width / 2 - destWidth / 2;
        var destY = canvas.height / 2 - destHeight / 2;

        context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, 
            destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
    };
    imageObj.src = "darth-vader.jpg";
};
```

If you choose to pursue the HTML5 route, you'll find plenty of other examples by searching.

Edit: I think Fantius may have proposed the most practical approach. You can create custom shapes with HTML5 canvas. [Here's](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/) a basic demonstration for creating a couple of non-rectangular shapes.

Comment: Do you know if this technique can be used to crop the image to a shape other that a rectangle? (say a wedge shape)?

Answer (score 0):

Pixastic has a simple Javascript image editor (uses Canvas):

Refer: http://www.pixastic.com/

Comment: That website now links to a random casino. I think this is the right link? Any updates would be appreciated https://enotionz.github.io/pixastic-docs/